# Netsuite, update value and save record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want to edit a record, then click "Save" and the field "custitem_con" to be updated with a new value and the record saved.

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(['N/currentRecord'],
function(currentRecord) {
function saveRecord (){
var objRecord = currentRecord.get();
var con = 'Success!...but record is not saved :(';
objRecord.setValue({
                fieldId: 'custitem_con',
                value: con,
                });
}
return {
saveRecord: saveRecord
};});
```

However while the field custitem_con gets the value, the record is not saved, but remains in edit mode. How do I get the record saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to allow the record to be submitted, you need to `return true` from the `saveRecord()` function, thus:

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(['N/currentRecord'],
function(currentRecord) {
function saveRecord (){
var objRecord = currentRecord.get();
var con = 'Success!...but record is not saved :(';
objRecord.setValue({
                fieldId: 'custitem_con',
                value: con,
                });
return true;
}
return {
saveRecord: saveRecord
};});
```